# How to calculate if points in N dimension are collinear, coplanar, cocubic, cotessar or co-X-spatial

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Given X is the spatial dimension of a plane/hyperplane, What's the best way to calculate if any set of points in N dimensions lie in the same 1D plane (collinear) / 2D plane (coplanar) / 3D plane (cocubic) / 4D plane (cotessar) / XD plane (co-X-spatial) etc.

I have tried using the rank of matrices of points as noticed  [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity) asper
[image]
 specifically what I did was e.g. if the rank is $<=$ 3 then the points are cocubic just like if the rank is $<=$ 2 for being coplanar, sadly that didn't work. Then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27241203/10138416) which is why I am asking about the best way to actually get this done.

> cubic and tessar from cubes and tesseracts

Comment: Are we dealing with points whose coordinates are exactly known?  If not, as typical for floating point arithmetic, then you might be interested in best approximation by $k$-dimensional hyper-planes.

Comment: How do you mean 'sadly that didn't work'?

Comment: @hardmath coordinates are exactly known

Comment: @Berci all 4D points I tested to be cocubic always turned out to be true (their ranks were <=3 but never greater, I mean for points that weren't cocubic too)

Comment: What about $(0,0,0,0),\ (1,0,0,0),\ (0,1,0,0),\ (0,0,1,0),\ (0,0,0,1)$? The corresponding matrix is the identity matrix, it has rank $4$.

Comment: currently am not with my pc, I would have to verify this with the implementation I made, could you try finding out the rank of these points for example: $(0,4,0,0),  (16,42,22,0), (28,26,0,0),  (2,16,5,20)$

Comment: $4$ points are *always* in one 3d affine subspace, just as $3$ points are always coplanar and $2$ points collinear.

Comment: woah... thanks for pointing this out, this must have been my mistake. I really appreciate